# Kial estas "la la" en ĉi tiu frazo?

Tags: article

En "La Eta Princo", sur paĝo 49 en [ĉi tiu e-eldono](http://i-espero.info/files/elibroj/eo%20-%20saint-exupery,%20antoine%20de%20-%20la%20eta%20princo.pdf), mi trovis la frazon

> “Libroj pri geografio,” diris la geografo, ”estas la la plej valoraj el ĉiuj libroj. [...]”

Ĉu la **"la la"** estas ĝuste? Ĉu "la plej" necesas unu plian "la"-n en certaj situacioj? Aŭ ĉu ĝi estas nur tajperaro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi pensas ke tio estas tajperaro.
Mi legis [tie](http://bulteno.esperanto-usa.org/2010/6/60-libroj.html) ke la elektronika formo plenegis je tajperaroj, kiu ne estas en la presita versio.
(Bedaŭrinde, mi ne havas la presitan version)

Comment: Sendube jes. Tajperaro.

Comment: Tre interesa intervjuo!

Answer (score 8):

Ĝi estas tajperaro. Mi kontrolis en du versioj de la libro kaj la teksto estas:

- la plej valoraj (malnova eldono)
- la plej seriozaj (nova eldono)

Mi efektive partoprenis en la traduko de la nova eldono - nur bagatele, per longeta diskuto kun la ĉef-tradukisto pri unu frazo - sed rekompence mi ricevis ekzempleron de la libro.

[image: Du versioj de La Eta Princo]

Comment: Dankon por trovi la lokon en realaj libroj!! Mi verŝajne supozis, ke tajperaroj konataj al la verkisto estas pli facile korektitaj en e-eldono.